# Access Spotify cached files

Tags: offline, android-11, spotify

How to use cached files in Spotify application under Android ?
The mentioned file extensions are ".file" , which are not normally playable, but it is clear from the size and type of archiving that they can be used offline by the application.  The threshold storage address

is as follows:
/internal storage/android/data/com.spotofy.music/files/spotifycash/storage

Comment: There's always a possibility for streaming platforms to encrypt the cache/offline files (i.e. DRM) so that only their app can play it exclusively.

Comment: Thank you .  Is there a way other than the normal mode in the software to download music in this space ?

Comment: @Merlin: Sorry but I don't understand your last comment. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I just want to be able to download music files from Spotify.

Comment: Spotify has an offline mode if you have a paid account. That is what they provide, of you want to use the downloaded files outside of Spotify Andrew already gave you the answer that those files are DRM encrypted and thus can't be used outside of Spotify.

Comment: got this [app](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3632423) from 4pda. guess with that source code someone can decode files

Comment: microsoft has blocked source code, one more reason to not use [github](https://github.blog/2020-11-16-standing-up-for-developers-youtube-dl-is-back). you can still find the binary patch on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/daylight/spotify-dogfood) and ask the author for [wiki](https://github.com/sergiocastell/spotify-dogfood/wiki/The-liborbit-jni-spotify.so-file)

Comment: @Merlin the problem is, when you use (or even subscribe to) Spotify, Spotify only gives you access to play audio files within their platform, but you don't own the audio files in the first place, so it's potentially illegal to download them for other uses outside of Spotify. There are of course other ways to achieve what you want, but I can't mention them due to personal reason.

Comment: @alecxs I don't think a more than 3 years old Spotify app will still work. Spotify releases new apps very frequently and the chance that one of those apps includes a protocol change is very high. I assume this is also done to make reverse engineering ineffective.

Comment: the app works fine no ads, i use it on android 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, those files might be stored in /root/data/data/spotify but wont be playable or even accessible without superuser privileges

Comment: yes . Yes I have access to the file cache in the storage location but unfortunately the files are apparently encrypted with the ".file" extension